# Is there way to apply QVBoxLayout to QFormLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qvboxlayout

I found some tutorial code online about QFormLayout:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QWidget()

    l1 = QLabel("Name")
    nm = QLineEdit()

    l2 = QLabel("Address")
    add1 = QLineEdit()
    add2 = QLineEdit()
    fbox = QFormLayout()
    fbox.addRow(l1, nm)
    vbox = QVBoxLayout()

    vbox.addWidget(add1)
    vbox.addWidget(add2)
    fbox.addRow(l2, vbox)
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    r1 = QRadioButton("Male")
    r2 = QRadioButton("Female")
    hbox.addWidget(r1)
    hbox.addWidget(r2)
    hbox.addStretch()
    fbox.addRow(QLabel("sex"), hbox)
    fbox.addRow(QPushButton("Submit"), QPushButton("Cancel"))
    win.setLayout(fbox)

    win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

The right bottom one is what the original GUI looks like.

When I dragged the widget horizontally, the right top one is what GUI looks like.

When I dragged the widget vertically, the left one is what GUI looks like.

It seems those labels and buttons will follow the horizontal change but failed to change as the main widget changes vertically. Is there anyway to do this to make all buttons and labels change dynamically?

Comment: Could you explain me better

Comment: Hi, I changed the description and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You want that when the widget expands vertically you also want the `QformLayout` to do it

Comment: yes,is there any way to do this? Thank you very much.